# What to do if a transaction fails?

Tags: database, transactions, software-design, distributed-transactions

So basically there is a game where you own a planet, you send ships to other planets, and after a bit you can own that new planet.

PlanetB is being attacked with a ship:

[PlanetA] ----> [PlanetB]

The process on ship arrival when the PlanetB is conquered is the following:

- The previous owner of the PlanetB has to pay back the money to the owner of the PlanetA (one db transaction T0)
- Now the owner of PlanetA needs to create a new deposit (one db transaction T1)
- Only if the previous transaction is successful we can change the ownership of the PlanetB to the owner of PlanetA

Note that transactions are done on another server and I can't join them both in one single transaction.

Basically money and deposits are stored in the database as they are important (on serverA), but the game planets and ships in memory (on serverB).

So the questions are:

- What to do if T0 fails because of an error that is of the database, for example I'm getting too many connections errors.? I could ignore it, but is not good because the owner of PlanetA will not receive the money of a new owned planet.
- Same for T1, the transaction fails for some strange db connection error. The player will not even get his planet. Will need to send another ship to try again, which is not optimal.

I should retry this over and over again, until when, it could stop that ship from entering the planet for long time.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a easy answer. All that sounds like the db system is slightly overloaded and should be configured to withstand bigger load.
Then all depends on how consistent you want to be. My first idea would be to offload the data to some other storage before the database is ready and then save there the data. You could add some messaging broker (e.g. zeromq) which is possibly capable to receive a bit amount of data and then in background (e.g. in batches) load data to database. Or you can do something similar by saving data in case of non-accessible database to a file (journal) at the server B. And trying to save data to database when possible.
Be aware that this "solution" makes your data changes eventually consistent. I mean If there are some offloaded data e.g. in the journal and you query the database they could not be saved and user can observe different data state at that point of time.

Comment: Is going to manage money so needs to be 100% reliable :) the thing is if you miss the boat (transaction fails when your conquer one planet) then you don't own that planet at all. you need to send another ship to conquer. That will affect a bit the game. Also I can't make the whole game to wait until that transaction is completed... So the problem is that I cannot handle the operation later as it doesn't make sense. For example at a later time, that planet is owned by another user or some other stuff happens.

Comment: Just by intereste, if you miss the boat then you don't own the planet but you don't lose the money, right?
Nevertheless my point was that if you use the database as the source of truth then it's the "synchronization point" of your infrastructure and it's the bottleneck that all the operation depends on. If it's the point maybe you should consider to somehow split the data load to the database - e.g. some not-so-important queries could be offloaded to some sidedatabase and the main database could have more resources for the money releated transactions.

Comment: yeah, so basically first will try to deposit your money if it succeeds you will own the planet. Yeah, I can offload but at the moment is doing just this and authentication, is a small piece for now. The question is about how to handle a failed transaction